# Проверка на разницу соответствия полей в таблицах

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Допустим у нас есть две похожие таблицы:

```
table1: field1(int), field2(int), field3(int);
table2: field1(int), field2(varchar), field3(int);
```

Можно ли написать SQL запрос который обнаружит и покажет разницу полей (**не записей**) между двумя этими таблицами?

Comment: Какой сервер БД?

Comment: в данный момент PG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте запрос к `information_schema.Columns`:

```
select t1.column_name, t1.data_type as data_type1, t2.data_type as data_type2 
from information_schema.Columns t1
join information_schema.Columns t2 on t1.column_name=t2.column_name
where t1.table_name='table1' and t2.table_name='table2'
```

Возможны варианты с разными типами `join` и предварительной подготовкой ключа, по которому будем сравнивать типы полей. Но в целом - смотреть туда.

Будет работать в PG, MS SQL, MySql. Не будет работать в [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739203/oracle-query-to-fetch-column-names), [SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386631/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-all-column-titles-in-a-table-in-sqlite), там используйте соответствующие механизмы.

Comment: красиво, спасибо большое